# Hypothesis a model is linear

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a data set which I describe by this nonlinear model:
$$Y_i=\theta_1 x+2\theta_3x^2+\frac{\theta_2 x^3}{3+exp(-\theta_4x +x^2)}+\theta_5+\epsilon_i$$

$$\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$
$$i=1,..,n$$

I have problems formulating a hypotheses that the model is linear and describing the testing of that hypotheses.

Any pointers, clues?

Comment: You should be more precise. What are your parameters? What ist your independent variable? Why should the modell be "in fact linear"? If x is your independent variable, then your model is not linear at all.

Comment: Your null would be $\theta_2 = \theta_3 = 0$ and $H_a$: at least one of them is nonzero. If there's evidence to reject the null then you can say with the corresponding confidence that the model is not linear.

Comment: Sorry about not being precise. I want to suggest a hypotheses that the model is linear and then show that the hypotheses can be rejected.